# Which .php File Controls WordPress Media Library?

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, media

I'm trying to modify the WordPress Media Library very slightly.

Currently when viewing it, if I click on the file name, it will being up the edit page for that piece of media in the current tab. However, I would like it to be that when I click the file name, the edit page will open in a new tab.

I assumed this would be as easy as adding `target="_blank"` to the html link.

But I cannot find the .php file in my WordPress install that controls the Media Library, could anyone tell me which file it is please?

Many thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you're looking for is located here: `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-media-list-table.php`.

However I don't recommend modifying that file. You want to avoid making changes to core files if at all possible. If you change that file, your modifications will be lost if you upgrade WordPress.

Instead, I would use javascript to add the `title="_blank"` attribute to those links. You'll need to [enqueue a js file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) and then write a simple script to update the links:

```
(function($) {
    $('.wp-list-table.media .media-icon a, .wp-list-table.media .column-title a')
        .attr('target', '_blank');
}(jQuery));
```

This is a less than perfect way to accomplish what you want, but I think it is preferable to modifying the core.